# How to handle unpermitted parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, strong-parameters

Given the following PUT request

domain/api/v1/conversations/id

```
{
  "group_id": "123456",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

If I use:

```
params.permit(:group_id)
```

I would have an ActionController::UnpermittedParameters: "found unpermitted parameters: :foo, :format, :id, :conversation"

I'm able to know the unpermitted parameters, but it is validating :format, id, and conversation.

So, If I use:

```
params.require(:conversation).permit(:group_id)
```

It works, ignoring the :foo parameter.

But I would like that if there are any unpermitted parameter, a exception to be thrown.
Is there a way to do that?
Or the right approach to accomplish that would be to use like this?

```
params.permit(:group_id, :format, :id, :conversation)
```

Comment: Just to point out on JSON response the invalid params that was send. This way, whoever is integrating with my app, would know what he is sending wrong. Does not seems right to me that I can send anything to the server and it does not reply saying it is unpermitted.

Comment: I was holding on the exception idea because it is already thrown when using just params.permit(), the ActionController::UnpermittedParameters returns just what I want. I could rescue from that get the message.